# Java block a main with a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog

I have a main class in java which call a JFrame Two.

But before call this JFrame Two, my main check a condition and if it's true, it call a JFrame One.

So, my main don't extends JFrame.

I want that my JFrame One stop my main until it been closed, then my main could call my JFrame Two.

I tried to make my JFrame One as a JDialog modal, but my main still running (probably because it isn't a JFrame ?)

Here a simplified part of my code :

```
File file = new File(PTA);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        FrameOne fo = new FrameOne(); //FrameOne Extends JFrame
    }
    FrameTwo ft = new FrameTwo();
```

So like you can see, my main will always call FrameTwo.

But i want that until FrameOne was closed, the main class stop running, so it don't call FrameTwo until FrameOne was closed.

I don't really know how a JDialog works, i tried to convert my JFrameOne in a JDialog with "setModal(true)" but my main class still running too.

Please can you help me ? My project is blocked by this problem...

Thanks for your attention and your help.

Regards,

Maxime OZENNE.

Comment: Please create and post a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, a [MCVE]. Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool.

Answer (score 3):

> i tried to convert my JFrameOne in a JDialog with "setModal(true)" but my main class still running too.

It doesn't work that way, you and you can't make a JFrame modal this way (the JFrame doesn't even have this method). Instead you're going to have to use a JDialog and not a JFrame, and create the dialog so that it's modal. Myself I avoid creating classes that extend JFrame or the like and instead gear my code towards creating JPanels, which can then be placed into JFrames or JDialogs, or JTabbedPanes, or swapped via CardLayouts, wherever needed. This will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI coding.

So on that note, I'd do something on these lines:

```
MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();

// assuming that the parent window JFrame is referenced by "myFrame"
JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(myJFrame, "My Dialog", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
myDialog.add(myPanel);
myDialog.pack();
myDialog.setVisible(true);
```

If this doesn't help, then please create and post your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) program, and let us help modify it.

Comment: So, if I understand, i'll convert my JFrameOne into a JPanel (So the code still the same ?)
Then i create JDialog like you did ? But "MyJFrame" is my main, and my main don't extends JFrame

Comment: @MaximeOzenne: You can't use the same code for a JPanel as for a JFrame, and this will involve some re-write. As for the rest, you don't have to have main extend JFrame, and again **none** of my classes do. You just have to have a **reference** to a displayed window such as a JFrame. Again if you need more help, create your [mcve].

Comment: Ok, so my main would call JFrameTwo, then if my condition is true, my main call a JDialog with a Panel built like my JFrameOne which block my JFrameTwo ?

Comment: @MaximeOzenne: sorry, but I don't know what you mean as you're asking about specifics about code I've not seen and don't fully understand. Again, if you could show code and explain in detail, or better try a possible solution and see if it works.

Comment: @MaximeOzenne: also note that a modal dialog will halt program execution even if the code is not being called from within a GUI or a JFrame. You could pass a `null` into the JDialog as the parent window if no window is available, and it will work, similar to a JOptionPane (which in fact is nothing more than a specialized JDialog). Also, I've often used JOptionPanes as quick and easy to make modal dialogs.

Comment: It's ok, i resolved my problem, thanks for your help.